# standard 404 html response

Tags: html, web, http-status-code-404

I have created a web server. There are certain pages that I would like to return the standard 404 error to the user (even though the pages exist in my browser).  I have seen many articles on how to make custom 404 error pages, but I specifically want to return the standard error page (on certain pages that do indeed exist), like when someone is browsing the internet and types an internet address that doesn't exist.  thanks in advance.

Edit: I would like to rephrase the question:

I'm using tomcat8 for the servlet. When typing http://myIp:8080 I get the default tomcat8 web page (according to the default index.html file that tomcat8 provides). Instead of this default page, I would like to have an 404 page not found error.  How do I change the default index.html file to go to a standard browser 404 page not found error?

Comment: First of all, it would be useful what kind of web server you are using (IIS, Apache, nginx...). Next, I'm not really sure this is really a programming related question and more a configuration related issue. In the later case, [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) might be of more help.

Comment: I'm using the Apache tomcat 8 server

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what stack are using but in general you are looking for redirect. Whatever you are using there should be possible to configure intetnal redirect  from pages you want to hide to page 404. However,  It is not clear why you want to hide pages from your users. I'm pretty sure if you post the reason behind someone can suggest a better solution for your problem.

Comment: Currently what I have done is changed the index.html default file (tomcat8) to display "Error 404" as the header text, but ideally I would like it to re-direct to the standard error 404 page that is displayed on the web browser.  The reason is that the website is meant for specific users only, and I don't want someone accidentally stumbling onto the website.

Comment: But how you distinguish between specific and not specific users?